# How to call a SQL Server stored procedure in asp file which returns a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to ASP.NET. First I created a database in SQL Server 2008, and in it, I created a stored procedure `Getdata`. I want to call this stored procedure from my ASP.NET page.

In ASP.NET, I have a master page with some other page like home, about etc. I want to run the `Getdata` stored procedure when the user clicks on `Home`.

The stored procedure is:

```
Create procedure Getdata
as 
begin
   select * from Log_Users
end
```

and my home page code is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <h2>This is a the HOME page.</h2>
</asp:Content>
```

and its aspx.cs file code is:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Master.PageName = "Home";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = "YourStoredProcName";
var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringName"].ConnectionString;
var con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameterName", parameterValue); //If any

//Open connection - load result into datatable
con.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
con.Close();
```

conStr can either be in that format (using the web.config stored connection string), or in as a raw string.  I'd recommend this way though.  After this runs you'll have a datatable (dt) that contains the result of your stored procedure, which you can manipulate as you please!

You can find the connection string by adding the database as a data source for the project, and finding it in the data source properties (there may be another way to do this).

Comment: Wherever you like, perhaps in the click handler for a button so you can click to fill the datatable. After the code you could also bind the datatable to a gridview using GridView.DataSource = dt; GridView.DataBind();

Comment: Can i place this code in aspx.cs file after this public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page...... ?

Comment: You could also just put it in the Page_Load, fill the data table, and bind it to a grid view or display the data in some other way, so it appears (to the user) as soon as you hit the page

Comment: Yes of course, as long as it's inside a method it will work, you won't see any output on the page from this code but the data will be loaded into the "dt" object

Comment: Mark up answer if it helped you!

Comment: M really sorry it is not working may b i cannot understand what to do... can u edit my file code for me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand("Getdata", myConnection))
    {
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

you may need to set this DataTable as Data Source of Gridview or something to display